# Creating array from another array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some array that look like this

```
$links =array('proizvodi','pokloni', 'kuhinja');
```

I need to create another array that will look like this

```
$linksNew =array('proizvodi/','proizvodi/pokloni/', 'proizvodi/pokloni/kuhinja/');
```

Txanks in advance

Comment: We cannot tell you if there is a pattern, you have to tell us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a primitive approach:

```
<?php
$input = ['proizvodi','pokloni', 'kuhinja'];
$output = [];
$previous = '';
foreach ($input as $entry) {
    $output[] = $previous . $entry . '/';
    $previous = end($output);
}
var_dump($output);
```

---

This is a version some might consider a bit more elegant:

```
<?php
$input = ['proizvodi','pokloni', 'kuhinja'];
$output = [];
$previous = '';
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$previous, &$output) {
    $output[] = $previous . $entry . '/';
    $previous = end($output);
});
var_dump($output);
```

---

The output of both versions obviously is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "proizvodi/"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "proizvodi/pokloni/"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "proizvodi/pokloni/kuhinja/"
}
```

Comment: Works for me without issue. If you experience an http status 500 (internal server error) the first thing _always_ to do is: take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the _specific_ issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a approach without a for or foreach loop

```php
$links = array('proizvodi','pokloni', 'kuhinja');

$newLinks = array_map(function($i) use ($links) {

    return implode(array_slice($links, 0, $i), '/') . '/';

}, range(1, count($links)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to think of a slicker way, but this works:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($links); $i++) {
    $linksNew[] = implode('/', array_slice($links, $i)) . '/';
}
$linksNew = array_reverse($linksNew);
```